# Migration of Kubernetes Master

Tags: kubernetes

I need to migrate my kubernetes master to another server.
How can we do that with all datas of the current running services, pod, rc ...
What do we need to backup , because kubernetes doc don't talk about this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two things that contain the master's identity are its IP address and a few different pieces of data from its local disk.

To make upgrades work on Google Compute Engine, [we mount the four important directories listed below to a persistent disk](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/e264db43499cb14a319f6a78185b018b0958d314/cluster/gce/configure-vm.sh#L239) and reserve the IP address of the VM, then detach the disk and IP and put them on a new VM. The directories saved are:

```
/var/etcd
/srv/kubernetes
/srv/sshproxy
/srv/salt-overlay
```

Comment: It's not necessary the IP (that depends on how you've deployed). It's the address at which the kubelets / kube-proxy processes reach the apiserver that matters. In some deployments it's an IP address; in others its a resolvable DNS name.

Comment: If you aren't using salt, keep in mind that in addition to the etcd database, you need to back up the authentication files used by the apiserver (the certificates, any basic / token auth csv files, etc).