# How to move Kubernetes master node from one server to another?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I have Kubernetes cluster with two nodes. One's role is Master.

I want to move master node to another physical server.

The possible way I see is to add another node and change its role to master.

How can I do that?  Is there any kind of instructions?
Is this the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a duplicate of [Migration of Kubernetes Master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239979/migration-of-kubernetes-master)

In fact, you just need to

- clone data from the disk
- change identity of the new server (IP address/DNS name)

**Update**

If you want to change master IP address in kubeadm config, check following references:

- replacing the IP address in all config files in /etc/kubernetes
- backing up /etc/kubernetes/pki
- identifying certs in /etc/kubernetes/pki that have the old IP address as an alt name
- deleting both the cert and key for each of them (for me it was just apiserver and etcd/peer)
- regenerating the certs using kubeadm alpha phase certs[2](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755)
- identifying configmap in the kube-system namespace that referenced the old IP
- manually editing those configmaps
  restarting kubelet and docker (to force all containers to be recreated)

Or take a look at this step-by-step [instruction](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/338#issuecomment-418879755)

Comment: if I can't change identity of the new server? is there a way to change it to new one in copied data?

Comment: @Alexey Anisimov did you have any success? What files or directories needed to be moved or copied over?