# What is the command use to change from master to a worker node in Kubenetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

This is a beginner's question, but I am stuck for that.

There is a cluster containing 2 nodes, "master" and "node01". Initially, I am in the "master" node console, now I want to do some version update on "node01", what is the command for me to switch to the node01 console?

```
master $ # my original console, which is of master node. 
master $ # what command I need to run to switch to next console ??? 
node01 $ ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move Kubernetes master node from one server to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163698/how-to-move-kubernetes-master-node-from-one-server-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: ssh into `node01`.

If `node01` doesn't have a DNS entry you can ssh to the IP address

```sh
ssh <username>@<IP Address of node01>
```

Make sure you have the right credentials/ssh keys.