# Is it possible to promote a Kubernetes worker node to master?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to promote a Kubernetes worker node to master to quickly recover from the loss of a master (1 of 3) and restore safety to the cluster? Preferably without disrupting all the pods already running on it. Bare metal deployment. Tx.

Comment: Etcd is co-lolated with the master nodes.

Comment: It is key to know how you deployed the cluster in the first place, but in general there is no "one button" solution to do that. There are a lot of moving parts in a master node that are simply not present in the workers.

Comment: It was setup with kubeadm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I think what you want to do at the end of the day is migrate to a different server. Try looking at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34239979/migration-of-kubernetes-master

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like a worker node can be promoted to master in general. However it is easy to sort out for a specific case:

- Control plane node disappears from the network
- Node is manually deleted: `k delete node2.example.com --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data`
- Some time later it reboots and rejoins the cluster

Check that it has rejoined the etcd cluster:

```
# k exec -it etcd-node1.example.com -n kube-system -- /bin/sh
# etcdctl --endpoints 127.0.0.1:2379 --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
    --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key \
    member list
506801cdae97607b, started, node1.example.com, https://65.21.128.36:2380, https://xxx:2379, false
8051adea81dc4c6a, started, node2.example.com, https://95.217.56.177:2380, https://xxx:2379, false
ccd32aaf544c8ef9, started, node3.example.com, https://65.21.121.254:2380, https://xxx:2379, false
```

If it is part of the cluster then re-label it:

```
k label node node2.example.com node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=
k label node node2.example.com node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
```